# How to access iis website from out side the network?

Tags: iis

I installed IIS on a laptop (win 7 professional 64 bit).

Created a website. I been able to view the website within the network.
If i type 192.168.0.227/vdv   (local host ip address)(laptop's ip).

Now i need to access this website from outside the network.

I bought a WiFi modem and connected to the lap (now lap is disconnected from LAN). The modem has a dynamic IP & lap is assigned 192.168.100.100. Now i need to access the website which is in the laptop from outside the network .

How to do ?

Comment: This is probably a question for Serverfault or Superuser.

Comment: Do you mean, that you want to connect another System to the Laptop (Server) via the WiFi you installed?

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your post correctly, you are running IIS locally but you are having problems connecting when your local IP changes.

By Default, IIS binds to all IP addresses, so it really shouldn't matter if you use your LAN ip or Modem IP. Either way, for simplicity you should either be using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or your machine name as your address. This won't change when your local IP does.

First see if http://localhost/vdv works. If it does then continue to use that, otherwise you may need to change the bindings in your local IIS installation or your application. Make sure it's not listening on a specific IP address.

Take a look at this article for more information: http://blogs.technet.com/b/chrad/archive/2010/01/24/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools.aspx